# Enforcing a specific commit message

Tags: git, hook, gerrit

My gerrit server version is- 2.14.7 and hooks plugin installed by default. We have around 20 repositories/projects in our server.

Currently we are using pre-commit hook. It is working perfectly on local machine, However to work globally for all gerrit projects on Gerrit Server side I have created folder /opt/gerrrit/hooks/

Then I have renamed my hook(pre-commit) to commit-received and changed as executable. And also in gerrit.config file updated with below,

```
[hooks]
path = /opt/gerrit/hooks
```

However still not working, Also In error_log i don’t see any error related with this hook.

I can see only below information.

**Info Mode:-**

```
[2018-07-18 09:12:09,506] [HTTP-75] INFO  com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.hooks.HookFactory : hooks.path: /opt/gerrit/hooks
[2018-07-18 09:12:09,510] [HTTP-75] INFO  com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.hooks.HookFactory : hooks.refUpdatedHook resolved to /opt/gerrit/hooks/ref-updated
[2018-07-18 09:12:09,552] [HTTP-75] INFO  com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.hooks.HookFactory : hooks.commentAddedHook resolved to /opt/gerrit/hooks/comment-added
[2018-07-18 09:16:47,036] [HTTP-93] INFO  com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.hooks.HookFactory : hooks.submitHook resolved to /opt/gerrit/hooks/submit
[2018-07-18 09:16:47,280] [HTTP-93] INFO  com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.hooks.HookFactory : hooks.changeMergedHook resolved to /opt/gerrit/hooks/change-merged
[2018-07-18 09:20:13,249] [ReceiveCommits-1] INFO  com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.hooks.HookFactory : hooks.commitReceivedHook resolved to /opt/gerrit/hooks/commit-received
[2018-07-18 09:20:13,407] [ReceiveCommits-1] INFO  com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.hooks.HookFactory : hooks.patchsetCreatedHook resolved to /opt/gerrit/hooks/patchset-created
```

**Debug Mode:-**

```
[2018-07-19 09:10:35,617] [HTTP-134] DEBUG com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.hooks.HookQueue : Hook file not found: /opt/gerrit/hooks/ref-updated
[2018-07-19 09:10:35,635] [HTTP-134] DEBUG com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.hooks.HookQueue : Hook file not found: /opt/gerrit/hooks/comment-added
[2018-07-19 09:10:37,004] [HTTP-113] DEBUG com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.hooks.HookExecutor : Hook file not found: /opt/gerrit/hooks/submit
[2018-07-19 09:10:37,154] [HTTP-113] DEBUG com.googlesource.gerrit.plugins.hooks.HookQueue : Hook file not found: /opt/gerrit/hooks/change-merged
```

So any other settings needs to be enabled? Kindy advise me.

Comment: You've read the [documentation for Gerrit hooks](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/hooks/+/master/README.md)?

Comment: What have you tried so far and where exactly are you struggling?

Comment: Edit your post and update it with the relevant parts of your gerrit configuration, please.

Comment: In our gerrit server inside the Gerrit installation path created hooks folder (/opt/gerrrit/hooks/) then copied my pre-commit.sh hook then restarted my gerrit service. After that tried on my local machine. But it didnot work. Also I added my hooks path in my gerrit.config file still unable to get it worked.
Gerrit.config
[hooks]
hooks.pre-commit = /opt/gerrrit/hooks/
So suggest the best way to deploy globally.

Comment: Is there a pre-commit hook mentioned in the documentation? Have you thought about how such thing should work on the _server_ side? (Commits are local!)

Comment: Check the [commit-received](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/hooks/+/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/hooks.md#commit_received) hook.

Comment: Debug mode log added. So do i need to create those files manually inside hooks folder? Plz confirm.

Comment: Is the ref-updated line in that output appearing when you push the new commits? submit and merged are not related to push but to additional actions executed.

Comment: You do not have to create these files. Stil, you could also give the `ref-updated` hook a try. I'm not aware of the exact differences (I assume it can contain multiple commits..?).

Comment: Yes, I was right: https://www.gerritcodereview.com/releases/2.14.md#Behavior-change-in-hook

Comment: Can you please post your `commit-received` hook file? If that returns non-zero exit code, you should not be able to push anything anymore (which would be a good test)

Comment: commit-received hook file added.

Comment: So you want to provide a template for the commit message?

Comment: yes you are right.

Comment: Sorry, this is absolute nonsense. Commits are created locally and not on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use pre-commit hooks on the server side with Git.

Gerrit offers a [commit-received](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/hooks/+/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/hooks.md#commit_received) hook, which you can use to reject incoming commits.

Comment: I have renamed my hook to commit-received and changed as executable. Also gerrit.config file updated with below, However still not working, So any other settings needs to be enabled.
[hooks]
     path = /opt/gerrit/hooks 

In error_log i dont see any error related with this hook

Comment: Did you adopt it to Gerrits arguments? I doubt that it is enough to just rename it.

Comment: Once again, edit your original post (not comment!) and add your config plus a minimal example of the hook, otherwise I feel unable to help.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please take care of proper formatting?

Comment: It gets executed for every pushed commit for every repo. Based on the passed project you could then decide if you want to apply certain checks or not. You do not have to execute the given command manually.